# Using a character operator to perform an operation

Tags: java

I'm having issues coming up with a solution for my calculator program that I'm working on. The issue I'm having is that I don't know of a way to get the operation to work. I've tried concatenating it into a String, and then performing the operation that way, but you can't do that. I've also tried having the operands and the operator (char b) in between the operands, but it wouldn't perform the operation. The only solution that I have right now, is to do a series of checks that determine what the operator is, and then perform the equation using that operator, such as `if (b == '-') { int answer = x-y;}`. The only issue I have with doing it that way, is that it feels sloppy and like it could be done in a more efficient way.

```
/**
 * Makes sure that char b is a binary operator and returns the value made from x b y
 * 
 * @param  x   first operand of integer value
 * @param  b   the operation value
 * @param  y   second operand of integer value
 * @return     the operation of x b y where b is the binary operator, +,-,/,*,% 
 */
public int binaryOperation(int x, char b, int y)
{
    if (!(b == '+' || b == '-' || b == '/' || b == '*' || b == '%')) 
    {
        System.out.println("The character provided is not a valid binary operator. Please use one of the following characters:"
        + " '+', '-', '/', '*', or '%'.");
    }
    else 
    {
        int answer = 
        return answer;
    }
}

/**
 * Makes sure that b is an unary operator and returns the value made from x b y
 * 
 * @param  x   first operand of with an integer value
 * @param  b   the operation value
 * @param  y   second operand 
 * @return     the operation of x b y where b is the unary operator, + or -
 */
public int unaryOperation(int x, char b, int y)
{
    if (!(b == '+' || b == '-')) 
    {
        System.out.println("The character provided is not a valid unary operator. Please use one of the following characters:"
        + " '+' or '-'.");
    }
    else 
    {
        String function = System.out.println(x + b + y);
        int answer = (int) function;
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should first try to make it work, before looking into how to make it better? I see some more serious issues - a unary operator operating on two arguments, for example.

Comment: This is all wrong from start to finish. By the time you get to evaluate the operation you already know what the operator is, and therefore that it is valid. You can't just arrive at a unary operator evaluator method without already knowing you had a valid unary operator. Otherwise how did you get there? There is no reason to even have methods called `binaryOperation()` and `unaryOperation().` You need to look up the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm or recursive descent expression parsers. And throw this away.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
if (b == '+'){
   return x+y;
}
else if (b == '-') { 
   return x-y;
}
```

etc...

Answer (score 3):

The better way to do that is with a switch statement, like this:

```
switch(b) {
    case '+':
        return x + y;
        break;
    case '-':
        return x - y;
        break;
    case '*':
        return x * y;
        break;

    ...

}
```

And so on. There is not a char converter to java operator if that's your questios. Hope it helps!

You can read more about switch statement and it's syntax here: [Switch Statement.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/switch_statement_in_java.htm)

Comment: Yes mate, no problem! :)

Comment: Well... Someone downvoted our answers because they are jealous that we answered the answers fast and they were still busy trying to think what should they do. Thanks mate

Comment: I didn't downvote any of the answers. At the time that I wrote that it was solved, there was only one answer, and I had not viewed this since then. I knew how to use switches, but since college is dumb, I'm not allowed to use anything other than the basics, even though I know how to utilize things such as switches.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ScriptEngineManager which has a way to perform `eval` function(eval of JavaScript).

Such as:

```
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
        try {
            Object result = engine.eval("(1 + 2)*3");
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (ScriptException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The code above output 9.